# Archivos eliminados por error

Tags: c#

Elimine por accidente unos archivos de mi proyecto en C#, & a relizarle cambios, o ejecutarlo me marca error por esos archivos que no se encuentran & tampoco e refleja las modificaciones realizadas... como e hago para recuperar esos archivos.
 EStos archivos son : Form_bajasVehiculos.cs

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Comment: Lo mejor es usar control de versiones, para la próxima ocasión.

Comment: Usas algún control de versiones?

Comment: si no esta en la papelera de reciclaje ni en tu control de versiones.. no esta mas...

Comment: Te aconsejo que empieces a utilizar control de versiones. Si no tienes, y los archivos no están en papelera... hay soluciones para recuperar archivos borrados, aunque las mejores son pagas (recomiendo EaseUs), también hay gratuitas (como Recuva). Todas tienen algo en común: entre más te demores en intentar más difícil será recuperar los archivos.

Answer (score 1):

Los archivos que borres en **Visual Studio** van a la papelera de reciclaje de Windows. A menos que la hayas limpiado, tus archivos deben estar allí.

**Basta con restaurarlos y agregarlos** a tu proyecto como elemento existente.